# Looping for ggplot how to use the for loop variable i inside the loop

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe (what is the dataframe? i,e is not important).
I am using that and plotting some point curves. like below

```
#EXP <- 3 (example)
#EXP_VEC <- c(1:EXP)

for (i in 1:EXP)
{
gg2_plot[i] <- ggplot(subset(gg2,Ei == EXP_VEC[i] ),aes(x=hours, y=variable, fill = Mi)) + geom_point(aes(fill = Mi,color = Mi),size = 3)
}
```

As you can see EXP_VEC = c(1,2,3.......) (Depends on user input Ex: if user inputs 2 then EXP_VEC = c(1,2))

Dataframe has Ei = 1,2,3,4,........

Now I have to do the plotting for all these Ei values depending on the user input.

Consider, EXP_VEC=3
now the for loop should produce three plots for Ei = 1 , Ei = 2 and Ei = 3
for this if the for loop I have written works then it would have been done and finished.

But obviously for loop is not working. I cant use aes_string because variable "i" is outside the aes().

Ex: consider the following dataset

```
dd<-data.frame(
    Ei = c(1L, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    Mi = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
    hours = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), 
    variable = c(0.1023488, 0.1254325, 0.1523245, 0.1225425, 0.1452354, 
    0.1853324, 0.1452369, 0.1241241, 0.0542232, 0.8542154, 0.021542, 
    0.2541254))
```

As you can see I have two sets of Ei, I want to plot 1st plot for Ei = 1 and then beside this plot I want to again plot for Ei = 2.

So I thought of saving the plots for Ei=1 and Ei=2 in two separate variables and then using then in some kind of cascade function which I am yet to find out.
How do I do it?

Is there a easy way to do this by just using ggplot without any loop?
If not then how can I call "i" value inside my for loop?

Comment: You use a for loop, but you also have `i=i+1` at the end of each loop.  I assume this is not indented.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was still in C...:)..I have edited it.

Comment: Would you mind to provide some data? And you need a list of plots?

Comment: @PauloCardoso ...Added further info..please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
plot_exp <- 
  function(i){
    dat <- subset(gg2,Ei == i )
    if (nrow(dat) > 0)
       ggplot(dat,aes(x=hours, y=variable, fill = Mi)) + 
              geom_point(aes(color = Mi),size = 3)
  }

ll <- lapply(seq_len(EXP), plot_exp)
```

`ll` is a list of plot of ggplot objects.

Comment: Extremely Helpful. Thank You. Any Idea on displaying those ggplot objects inside ll in the layout manner. (Just like one after the other) (Both... real time display on screen and through PDF)

Comment: @statisticalbeginner something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23747514/640783)

Comment: I tried with grid.arrange but its not working any idea on this one?          > grid.arrange("ll[1]","ll[2]",tableGrob(head(iris)), nrow=2, as.table=TRUE, main="test main",sub=textGrob("test sub", gp=gpar(font=2)))
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
  input must be grobs!

Comment: Find the solution to the above problem with do.call function.             pdf("foo.pdf")
plot_exp <- 
  function(i){
    dat <- subset(gg2,Ei == i )
    ggplot(dat,aes(x=hours, y=variable, fill = Mi)) + 
      geom_point(aes(color = Mi),size = 3)
  }

ll <- lapply(seq_len(EXP), plot_exp)
do.call(grid.arrange,  ll)
dev.off()                                                                     Still working on Labels and Legends though....thanks anyway..:)