# Use forcat::fct_reorder to sort plots within facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have data with Country level stats over time.  I use `facet_wrap()` to plot by Country but I want to order the plots based on only the most recent value (2015) in descending order.  I've tried to use `transform()` but that orders only on the first values (2005).  I think `forcats::fct_reorder()` could get me there but I have not been successful in inserting in any of the arguments for `facet_wrap()`.  Is this even possible?  I'd prefer not to have to do a `grid_arrange()` [as this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364326/separate-ordering-in-ggplot-facets/11364998#11364998) if possible.

```
Country <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z')
`2005` <- c(500, 700, 600, 900, 800, 1000)
`2010` <- c(900, 600, 800, 1000, 500, 700)
`2015` <- c(1000, 900, 500, 800, 700, 600)

df1 <- data.frame(Country, `2005`, `2010`, `2015`)

gather1 <- gather(df1, "Year", myValue, 2:4)

gg1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = gather1, aes(x = Year, y = myValue, group = Country), size = 1.5, color = "orange") +
  facet_wrap(~ Country, ncol = 3) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = (35/50))
gg1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go!

```
gather2 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(Country=fct_reorder(Country, `2015`)) %>%
    gather("Year", myValue, 2:4)

gg2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = gather2, aes(x = Year, y = myValue, group = Country), size = 1.5, color = "orange") +
  facet_wrap(~ Country, ncol = 3) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = (35/50))
gg2
```

[image]

Comment: Booyah! That was it... adding it to my gather() functions rather than the facet_wrap.  Thanks.